# SQL Search using LOOP and Array

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I would like to make a query which search in a table but not as simply as u think.

I have a mixed array (for example the search key is 'second world war' and from this i create mixed array like this 'second', 'second world', 'second world war', 'war second' etc.) and i want to get the best match from it. My idea is i go through the array by a loop and compare the two word caracters and put the percentage result to a column than order the result by the calculated percent.

I found a function which count the parcentage but how to create a query which go thorugh the array and call the function?

Sorry, but im not enough good in sql :/

```
SELECT 
    P.FullName, 
    K.Shortname, 
    (P.VoteSumm / P.VoteCount) AS Rate, 
    [dbo].GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching](P.FullName, CurrentName)
FROM [Test].[dbo].Table1 AS P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Test].[dbo].Table2 AS UC ON UC.ID = P.UcID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Test].[dbo].Table3 AS K ON K.ID = P.KarID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Test].[dbo].Table4 AS PV ON PV.OwnerID= P.ID
WHERE
    (P.Deleted IS NULL) 
    AND
    (P.FullName LIKE '%kiss%' 
        OR P.FullName LIKE '%kisstamás%' 
        OR P.FullName LIKE '%tamás%') 
    OR 
    (P.Email IN ('kiss','kiss tamás','tamás') 
        OR UC.ShortName IN ('kiss','kiss tamás','tamás') 
        OR UC.Name IN ('kiss','kiss tamás','tamás') 
        OR K.ShortName IN ('kiss','kiss tamás','tamás') 
        OR K.Name IN ('kiss','kiss tamás','tamás'))
```

Here is my code, but the "current name" is just example. I dont know how to do that :/

Comment: Please show your code that you already achieve until now.

Comment: Most of the time when you need a loop in sql you're doing it wrong. In most cases you can figure out a way to do it in a little more advanced select query. Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Is all of this code in a Store Procedure which you call from some server code? If so then you should have CurrentName as input parameter for the stored procedure and then in "GetPercentage..." check some things and give it a percentage. Like count the total number of characters that are the same in fullname as currentName and more depending on if they are in the correct order and such.

Comment: No. I sad the current name is just an example. I would like to compare each world ('kiss','kiss tamás','tamás') with the p.FullName. This is just a query, not a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to store this 'array' in a table (one record per search term) then you would simply do this:

Assuming you stored the list of search terms in table `SearchTerm`, column `Term`:

```
SELECT P.FullName, T.Term
FROM [Test].[dbo].Table1 AS P
INNER JOIN
SearchTerm T
ON
(
  P.FullName LIKE '%' + T.Term + '%'
  OR 
  P.Email LIKE '%' + T.Term + '%'
)
WHERE P.Deleted IS NULL
```

This will compare `FullName` and `Email` to all of the  terms in the table and return the matches

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "loop" individually record by record use a CURSOR. See an example here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms180169(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic way to do what you say you are trying to achieve.

```
 select yourfields
 from yourtables
 where 1 = 2

 code to start your loop
 or somefield like '%SomeVariableDefinedInYourLoop%'
 code to stop your loop
```

The details depend on whether you are writing your code at the application or database level.  They also depend on the database engine and/or programming language.